# multiprocessing in python: AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing, but I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'processLine' on <module '__main__'
```

(The processLine function returns word, so I guess the problem is here, but I don't know how to get around it)

```
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(4)
jobs = []
Types =[]

def processLine(line):
     line = line.split()
     word = line[0].strip()
     return word

with open("1.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
     for line in f:
          word = (jobs.append(pool.apply_async(processLine,(line))))
          Types.append(word)
     filtered_words=[]
     with open("2.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
          for line in f:
               word = jobs.append(pool.apply_async(processLine,(line)))
               if word in Types:
                    filtered_words = "".join(line)
     print(filtered_words)

for job in jobs:
    job.get()

pool.close()
```

And this is what I get:
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:

Process ForkPoolWorker-2:

Process ForkPoolWorker-3:

Process ForkPoolWorker-4:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap

```
self.run()
```

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker

```
task = get()
```

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 345, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'processLine' on

Traceback (most recent call last):

Traceback (most recent call last):

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", 
line 249, in _bootstrap

```
self.run()
```

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker

```
task = get()
```

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 345, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 345, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'processLine' on 
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'processLine' on 
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()

File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", 
line 345, in get

```
return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
```

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'processLine' on

Comment: If `(line)` needs to be a tuple, do `(line,)`. A comma makes a tuple, not the parens.

Comment: No, line doesn't have to be a tuple.

Comment: Which actual line raises the error? Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Also, I am unable to reproduce your error by just running this in a Py3.6.2 interpreter...

Comment: What platform (Linux? Windows?) are you running on?

Comment: Mac OS X. if __name__ == '__main__': didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

The `multiprocessing` module needs to be able to import your module safely.  Any code not inside a function or class should be protected by the standard Python import guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...code goes here...
```

But there are other problems with your code.  For example, you've got:

```
word = jobs.append(pool.apply_async(processLine,(line)))
```

...but `append` doesn't return a value, so this will always assign `None` to `word`.

Rather than using a `for` loop to repeatedly call `pool.apply_async`, you may want to consider using `pool.map_async` instead, or just `pool.map` if you don't actually need the asynchronous behavior.

Comment: Does this explain OP's issue?

Comment: Does it not? I mean, obviously I think it does or I wouldn't have bothered posting it here.  I suspect that the unprotected code in the file is causing the error, but since it's not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't actually try running it myself without futzing around with the code more than I want.

Comment: I dunno, was able to run the code fine with made up inputs. Didn't get OP's error or need the guard block.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the AttributeError issue by using VS Code in administrator mode to run it instead of Anaconda Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. So, I put all functions in another `.py` file and imported `ipnyb`, and called them inside the main function.